# Get Maximum Value

Tags: ms-access

I am using MS Access database. I have a table (Proposal) with the following properties:
ProposalID - PK, Title, RequestedAmount, ResearcherID - FK

I want to run an SQL query to get the candidate that has requested for the highest amount.
My query that didn't work is:

```
Select ProposalID, Title, Max(RequestedAmount) AS Budget, ResearcherID
From
Proposal;
```

I get this error:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'ProposalID' as part of an aggregate function

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use aggregated fields with not aggregated fields you will have to use `Group by` with the not aggregated fields.
But in your case IMHO you are searching for:

```
Select ProposalID, Title, RequestedAmount AS Budget, ResearcherID
From
Proposal
where RequestedAmount=(Select Max(RequestedAmount) from Proposal)
```

Comment: what about ties?

Comment: @MitchWheat I know `Tie` from SQL-Server, do you know from MS-Access?